# How to rotate a container based on device orientation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, orientation, augmented-reality, sensors

I'm working on a location-based AR app in Flutter, and at first I'm trying to rotate a container using the device orientation.

I'm using the **flutter_sensors** package to get data from the accelerometer and the magnetometer of the device, and then I'm calculating a rotation matrix based on those values with the following function :

```
List<double> getRotationMatrix( vect.Vector3 gravity, vect.Vector3 geomagnetic) {
  List<double> result = List<double>(9);
  double ax = gravity[0];
  double ay = gravity[1];
  double az = gravity[2];
  final double ex = geomagnetic[0];
  final double ey = geomagnetic[1];
  final double ez = geomagnetic[2];
  double hx = ey * az - ez * ay;
  double hy = ez * ax - ex * az;
  double hz = ex * ay - ey * ax;
  final double normH = math.sqrt(hx * hx + hy * hy + hz * hz);
  if (normH < 0.1) {
    return null;
  }
  final double invH = 1.0 / normH;
  hx *= invH;
  hy *= invH;
  hz *= invH;
  final double invA = 1.0 / math.sqrt(ax * ax + ay * ay + az * az);
  ax *= invA;
  ay *= invA;
  az *= invA;
  final double mx = ay * hz - az * hy;
  final double my = az * hx - ax * hz;
  final double mz = ax * hy - ay * hx;
  result[0] = hx;
  result[1] = hy;
  result[2] = hz;
  result[3] = mx;
  result[4] = my;
  result[5] = mz;
  result[6] = ax;
  result[7] = ay;
  result[8] = az;

  return result;
}
```

I'm then getting the orientation angles based on this rotation matrix

```
List<double> getOrientation(List<double> r) {
  List<double> result = List<double>(3);
  if (r.length == 9) {
    result[0] = math.atan2(r[1], r[4]);
    result[1] = math.asin(-r[7]);
    result[2] = math.atan2(-r[6], r[8]);
  } else {
    result[0] = math.atan2(r[1], r[5]);
    result[1] = math.asin(-r[9]);
    result[2] = math.atan2(-r[8], r[10]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Then I'm displaying a container that should follow the device

```
if (_rotationMatrix != null)
            Center(
              child: Transform(
                transform: Matrix4.identity()
                  ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
                  ..rotateX(_orientationAngles[0])
                  ..rotateY(_orientationAngles[1])
                  ..rotateZ(_orientationAngles[2]),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            )
```

Unfortunately, the container is not rotating as expected, and I'm not sure where the errors are

Full code available here : https://github.com/RobinLbt/orientationExampleFlutter

Answer (score 0):

You are reinventing wheels for something that already exists. Extends the class `WidgetsBindingObserver` and add device orientation listener to your page by overring the method `didChangeMetrics()`. Then check the orientation with `Orientation.portrait` or `Orientation.landscape`. Depending on the value update some variable to notify your container rotation

Comment: Thanks dm_tr, but I need to raw values and not only the state of the orientation (pitch,roll,azimuth)